# For each multiple of 10 and 50 do something

Tags: java

I am in Java, and i'd like to know how I could do that. Here a small exemple I have so far but I have to make the same things with 50. So here comes the problems.

```
if(taskCompleted/10 == Math.round(Math.random()){
taskPoints = 20;
} else if(taskCompleted/50 == Math.round(Math.random()){
taskPoints = 60;
}
```

Otherwise I can explain it in word :

Each time taskCompleted is equals to a multiple of 10 (10,20,30,40 etc...), taskPoints equals 20 otherwise if each time taskCompleted is equals to a multiple of 50 (50,100,150,200) then taskPoints equals 60.

I hope you understand what I wanna do.

Comment: And why the random numbers? Also if we disregard them you have already implemented you goal. So what is the question?

Comment: May be [John](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1363819/john) wanted to use the random numbers like this: **`if( (taskCompleted=Math.round(Math.random())) % 10 == 0)`**

Answer (score 6):

```
if(taskCompleted % 50 == 0){
   taskPoints = 60;
} else if(taskCompleted % 10 == 0){
   taskPoints = 20;
}
```

Use modulus which will return the remainder. That will solve your problem. Look carefully for the condition, I am checking 50 before checking for 10. As any multiple of 50 is also a multiple of 10. So if you put 10 you will never hit 50.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Well this part of the question if you read section containing `Otherwise I can explain it in word :`

Answer (score 4):

```
if(taskCompleted % 50 == 0){
       //do something
}else if(taskCompleted % 10 == 0){
       //do something
}
```

Comment: hint: can you find a number is a multiple of 50 but is not a multiple of 10?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to previous answers except its more efficient to nest them. It can't be a multiple of 50 unless its a multiple of 10.

```
if (taskCompleted % 10 == 0)
   taskPoints = taskCompleted % 50 == 0 ? 60 : 20;
```

Comment: i can't understand how it will be more efficient. Above code will always have two comparisons for multiples of 50 as multiple of 50 is also multiple of 10. you can say its more elegant though...:)

Comment: Assuming most numbers are not multiples of 10. e.g. 9/10 of random numbers, there is one check only.

Comment: gotcha....the question is not very clear regarding the possible values of `taskCompleted`. +1 Good alternative though...

Comment: If you know the values are always multiples of 10, you wouldn't need to check for it. (Perhaps you might add an `assert` instead)

Comment: as its mentioned in the `Otherwise I can explain it in word :` they can be multiple of 10 or 50. So if I assume the numbers are 10, 50, 30, 100,150...etc...we can get way with just testing for multiple of 50 n the rest are all multiple of 10.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(taskCompleted % 10 == 0) { 
    taskPoints = 20;
}
if(taskCompleted % 50 == 0) { 
    taskPoints = 60;
}
```